# How to add an 'Offer' for a 'House' (which is not a 'Product' sub-type)?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

My idea is put a `House` definition and then a `Product` with a `Offer`. But I do not sell other product, I sell a house.

The `Product` scheme has a `Offer` schema inside, but `House` scheme do not have it. How can I do to put a schema `Offer` inside my `House` schema definition?

For now I have this code:

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "House",
"numberOfRooms": "4",
"floorSize": {
    "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
    "unitCode": "metros cuadrados",
    "value": "120",
    "description": "En Venta piso amplio, exterior, salón, cocina, 4 dormitorios, 1 cuarto de despensa/lavadora, 2 baños (con ventanas), 1 terraza, 5 armarios empotrados, plaza de garaje y 2 rochos (1 bajo cubierta y otro al lado plaza garaje). 120 m2 en planta. 4ª planta "
},
"address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressCountry": "España",
    "addressLocality": "Burela",
    "addressRegion": "A Mariña",
    "postalCode": "27880",
    "streetAddress": "Lamestra 9",
    "description": "A 130 metros de la playa "
},
"geo": [
    "-7.360289",
    "43.662696"
],
"hasMap": "http://www.softgalia.com/mapapisoburela",
"photos": "http://dechado11.softgalia.com/galerias/index",
"telephone": "677524729"
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: notice that `@House` is a `@Place` You need to use `@Offer` where `itemOffered` is `@Product` (house) and `availableAtOrFrom` is `@Place` (insert your code above)

Comment: I don't understand so well. You say I must to use **Product** schema and add inside it **house** schema using the **additionalType** property

Comment: `@Offer` `itemOffer` `@Product` `availableAtOrFrom` `@Place`

Answer (score 1):

The [`itemOffered`](http://schema.org/itemOffered) property expects a `Product` or `Service` value, but `House` is neither. And for the other direction: The [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers) property can’t be specified on `House`, but on `Product`, `Service`, `CreativeWork` etc.

If you offer to sell a house, this house becomes a product. So you should provide an entity that has two types: `House` *and* `Product`.

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Offer",
  "itemOffered": 
  { 
    "@type": ["House", "Product"]
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": ["House", "Product"],
  "offers": 
  { 
    "@type": "Offer"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do You think this new code is better than the code posted on Apr 19?

Comment: @MiguelRodriguez: "Better" is hard to say. But in my first paragraph I mentioned what the expected values for the `itemOffered` property are, and the JSON-LD in your answer uses a value that is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jay Gray for your help. This is my code now.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Offer",
    "price": "155.000 €",
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "availableAtOrFrom": 
    {
        "@type": "Place",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "addressCountry": "España",
                "addressLocality": "Lugo",
                "addressRegion": "Lugo",
                "postalCode": "27002",
                "streetAddress": "Primavera 40"
          },
          "telephone": "+34 677524729",
          "geo": 
          {
            "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
                "latitude": "-7.360232",
                "longitude": "43.662330",
                "postalCode": "27002"
           }
     },
    "itemOffered": 
    { 
      "@type": "House",
      "numberOfRooms": "4",
      "floorSize": {
          "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
          "unitCode": "metros cuadrados",
          "value": "120",
          "description": "En Venta piso amplio, exterior, salón, cocina, 4 dormitorios, 1 cuarto de despensa/lavadora, 2 baños (con ventanas), 1 terraza, 5 armarios empotrados, plaza de garaje y 2 rochos (1 bajo cubierta y otro al lado plaza garaje). 120 m2 en planta. 4ª planta "
      },
      "amenityFeature": "Al 130 metros de la playa O Cantiño, y en pleno centro de Burela. Supermercado a 150 metros y a 70 metros del parque Rosalía de castro y al mismo tiempo es una zona tranquila. Su situación es inmejorable.",
      "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "addressCountry": "España",
          "addressLocality": "Burela",
          "addressRegion": "A Mariña",
          "postalCode": "27880",
          "streetAddress": "Lamestra 9",
          "description": "A 130 metros de la playa "
      },
      "geo": [
          "-7.360232",
          "43.662330"
      ],
      "hasMap": "https://www.google.es/maps/place/43%C2%B039'44.4%22N+7%C2%B021'36.8%22W/@43.6623443,-7.3690083,3324m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sR%C3%BAa+da+Lamestra,+Burela!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d43.6623297!4d-7.3602321",
      "photos": [ "http://dechado11.softgalia.com/galerias_imagenes/foto-de-la-entrada-vista-hacia-el-despacho", 
                  "http://dechado11.softgalia.com/galerias_imagenes/bano-piso-venta-burela"      
                ],
      "telephone": "677524729"
      }
    }   
}
```